# Django error: cannot import name pbkdf2

Tags: python, django

When I run my Django app, I get the following error:

```
   ViewDoesNotExist at /
    Could not import sales.views. Error was: cannot import name pbkdf2
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    localhost:8000/
    Django Version: 1.3.2
    Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
    Exception Value:    
    Could not import sales.views. Error was: cannot import name pbkdf2
    Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback, line 167
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/rodrigo/Develop/Projects/SaleSystem/sales',
     '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't you have a proper traceback that can tell you exactly where the import statement is from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It was a conflict between versions of django (1.3 and 1.4).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
pip install pbkdf2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, in your views.py, you try to import pbkdf2, which fails.
could you copy your import in views.py

did you try this import in python from the shell ?

Comment: I'm not trying to import pbkdf2 in my views.py. I don't know where this come from.

Comment: which Django version are you using ? It seems that pbkdf2 is shipped in Django 1.4. It's a key derivation function used to hash password. You may use it in a function of your views.py

Comment: Resolved. It was a conflict between versions of django (1.3 and 1.4). I uninstalled both, and then installed version 1.4.